# Accessing bash completions for specific commands programmatically

Tags: bash, shell, tab-completion, bash-completion

I'm trying to write a small command launcher application, and would like to use bash's tab completions in my own completion system. I've been able to get a list of completions for general commands using `compgen -abck`.
However, I would also like to get completions for specific commands: for instance, the input `git p` should display completion for git's commands.

Is there any way I can use `compgen` to do this? If not, are there any other ways I can get a list of completions programmatically?

*[EDIT: To clarify, I'm not trying to **provide** completion to bash - my app is a GUI command launcher. I'd simply like to use bash's existing completions in my own app.]*

Comment: I hacked up this script a while back which gives you pretty accurate [Man-page Bash Completion](http://blog.dblevins.com/2010/03/man-page-based-bash-completion.html) I know other people have done similar things with parsing `--help` option output.

Comment: Great script, but not quite what I'm trying to achieve. Thanks anyway for linking to it though.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I don't really know how it works, but the [awesome window manager](https://awesome.naquadah.org/) uses the following Lua code for getting access to bash completion's result:

https://github.com/awesomeWM/awesome/blob/master/lib/awful/completion.lua#L119

1. Via `complete -p` we find `complete -o bashdefault -o default -o nospace -F _git git`. We remember "_git" for later.
2. The length of "git l" is 5, so we set COMP_COUNT=6. We are completing the first argument to "git", so COMP_CWORD=1.

All together we use the following script:

```
__print_completions() {
    printf '%s\n' "${COMPREPLY[@]}"
}

# load bash-completion functions
source /etc/bash_completion

# load git's completion function
_completion_loader git

COMP_WORDS=(git l)
COMP_LINE='git l'
COMP_POINT=6
COMP_CWORD=1
_git
__print_completions
```

Output: "log"

Comment: The code appears to do pretty much exactly what I want to do with my app. I'll need to port it to regular Bash, but it's still very helpful. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I did some testing and this is what is run to complete "git l": /usr/bin/env bash -c 'source /etc/bash_completion; __print_completions() { for ((i=0;i<${#COMPREPLY[*]};i++)); do echo ${COMPREPLY[i]}; done }; COMP_WORDS=(git l); COMP_LINE="git l"; COMP_COUNT=6; COMP_CWORD=1; _git; __print_completions'

Comment: "_git" is found via "complete -p" which prints "complete -o bashdefault -o default -o nospace -F _git git". So if the first word is "git", call "_git". COMP_COUNT is the length of the string so far plus one. COMP_CWORD is the word to complete (first one is index 0).

Comment: Thanks, this'll be perfect. I was thinking of answering the question myself to provide the Bash code and abstract way of doing this, but you've done it for me :P. Anyway, I've awarded you the bounty -  thanks again for your help!

Comment: Hey great!  Thanks for working this out.  Note that for the sake for readability/convenience, you can replace the `for ((..;..;..))` statement with `for reply in "${COMP_REPLY[@]}"` (and then `echo "$reply"` inside the loop).  Also: `i` in your example, or `reply` in my proposal, should be declared as `local` to avoid clobbering identically named globals.

Comment: FYI Bash now uses dynamic completion loading, which requires the use of `_completion_loader git` to load git's completion function `_git`. Also I was unable to find any reference to `COMP_COUNT`. The correct var is `COMP_POINT`. Note, `COMP_POINT` is not used directly in completion scripts, but is used indirectly via commonly-used helper functions in */usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion*.

Comment: Not working for me. Does it have to do with the script being non-interactive? My completion turns out to be `_minimal` when I run `_completion_loader`.

Answer (score 2):

Check in the `/etc/bash_completion.d/` directory. This is where the different command completion scripts stay.

Comment: I have had a poke around in `/etc/bash_completion.d/`, but haven't yet worked out an easy way to get the completions contained within yet very easily. (I'm using Python to access the completions, making things slightly more complicated.)  
I was hoping there might be a simpler way of accessing command-specific completions.

Answer (score 1):

Quite an old question, but in the mean time I've [implemented a script](https://github.com/3v1n0/zsh-bash-completions-fallback/blob/master/bash-completions-getter.sh) that handles this to reuse completions with ZSH