# how to get autocomplete programmatically?

Tags: autocomplete, terminal, terminal-emulator

I would like to get autocomplete suggestions for a command line (e.g. `git`)
but through code in `nodejs`

so basically, I want to write code that given a command line, gets the autocomplete result.

for example: `git b` should output `bisect blame branch bundle`

so far I've tried using shelljs with the following:

```
shell.exec('git b\t\t', function(code, output){
    console.log(output); 
})
```

but I keep getting errors from git. `'b' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.`

EDIT

currently I am using solution from: 
[Accessing bash completions for specific commands programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3520936/accessing-bash-completions-or-specific-commands-programmatically)

but this solution is very specific to OS and command. 
I am still interested in a library that will do it for me or some real easy solution.

how to get this done? is there a better way to resolve this?