# Creating a tab completion script. In one case I want to use the completion for another command (e.g. git), is it possible?

Tags: bash, git, ubuntu, tab-completion

So I have some commands I am scripting up:

all-build.sh
all-git.sh

These run commands on multiple folders and spawn output windows (running tail -f on logs) and all sorts of other things.

However I they each take different commands and I want tab completion

So I read a tutorial on tab completion and I have the all-completion.bash script as shown here:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

complete -W "param1 param2 param3" all-build.sh
complete -W "status log push pull" all-git.sh
```

As you can see the all-build auto complete params are my own custom ones and I am happy with that. However the git ones are a repeat of some of the actual git parameters. So really what I want is something like:

```
complete <use git completion> all-git.sh
```

So that when I do `all-git submodule upd<tab>` it auto completes to `all-git submodule update` using git's auto complete.

Is that possible?

Comment: what you may need is [https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash)?

Comment: @YiTang hmm... I don't  understand how to use this.... I already have git installed and it has tab completion so I think this is already sourced somewhere - bit that is for `git` command. How would I get it to work for my `all-git` command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We might use `_completion_loader`, (which is used to define completions *on the fly*) in order to load `git` completions.

Then we might observe in official [git-completion.sh](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash#L3330) file, that function used to complete git "submodules" is called `_git`, so we can simply pass it to `complete` via `-F <function>` option, see [complete documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Programmable-Completion-Builtins.html).

So by writing

```
source /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
_completion_loader git

complete -F _git all-git.sh
```

we can achieve desired behaviour (if I got your issue correctly).

**Note**: That `bash_completion` script, might be located on your machine in different folder. I've tested it on *Ubuntu 16.04* with *bash 4.3.48*.

**EDIT**: In case this doesn't fully solve your issue, I believe this is the way you want to go :). You can pretty much bend the solution for your needs.

**EDIT-2**: I've also assumed, you have already installed and working git completions.

**EDIT-3**: I've found a few interesting links, which are not solving your particular issue, but can give some light and deeper knowledge:

- [Accessing tab-completion programmatically in Bash](https://brbsix.github.io/2015/11/29/accessing-tab-completion-programmatically-in-bash/)
- [Perform tab-completion for aliases in Bash](https://brbsix.github.io/2015/11/23/perform-tab-completion-for-aliases-in-bash/)
- [Accessing bash completions for specific commands programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3520936/accessing-bash-completions-for-specific-commands-programmatically/3640096#3640096)

Comment: wow....sweet! - that just works. I don't quite get your comment about "the function used to complete git 'submodules' is called _git".  I tested this and it seems to do auto complete for all git functions not just git submodules... or did I miss understand!?...anyway - that is so awesome you deserve +85!

Comment: Sorry - I have marked up the answer +25, but I have to wait for 19 more hours until I can mark up the bounty : (  ... if I forget (which I won't) but just in case ping me a message tomorrow!!

Comment: Glad to help! Answer to `_git` related question: Basically we are using/calling a `_git` function from `git-completion.sh`. No worries :)

Comment: ah ha... plus 50 sir, well deserved : )

Comment: You should not be using `_git` directly, it's better to use `__git_complete`.

Answer (score 2):

It's very simple:

```
source /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/git
__git_complete all-git.sh __git_main
```

The `__git_complete()` function is a helper to create Git completions, it's used by Git itself like this: `__git_complete git __git_main`. You can use it for specific commands, like `__git_complete all-submodule.sh _git_submodule`.

It's specifically designed for this, so no need to complicate it more.